# If I use g++ as my compiler, how do I scan a c++ file with the clang static analyzer?

Tags: c++, clang-static-analyzer

I use g++ to compile my C++ project.  When I try to use the [clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/index.html) ([scan-build](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html)) to check my code, I get an error:

```
>> scan-build g++ main.cpp
could not find clang line
```

How do I use the scan-build tool with g++?

Comment: From [the source](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/scan-build/ccc-analyzer), scan-build is looking for the line that contains `-cc1`.

Comment: I'm not sure that you even should be able to. Should you not be using `llvm-g++`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that scan-build is having trouble recognizing "g++" as the compiler command.  It expects "clang" or "gcc".  If you replace "g++" with "gcc -lstdc++" to build your project, the scan-build tool will work properly.

```
>> scan-build gcc -lstdc++ main.cpp
main.cpp:7:3: warning: Assigned value is garbage or undefined
  int y = x;
  ^       ~
1 warning generated.
scan-build: 1 bugs found.
scan-build: Run 'scan-view /var/folders/2l/2l6vhCnVFNad-O8ryd5YO++++TI/-Tmp-/scan-build-2011-09-18-2' to examine bug reports.
```